# Is this a good way to handle sessions in ASP.Net MVC 4 web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

### WHAT I DID

I am using this SessionHelper as a common shared class for managing session object in ASP.Net MVC 4 app. This class uses singleton/static objects for accessing members. I'm new to architecture and all. So I want to know if this scenario is safe for web apps where we have multiple users accessing the app, simultaneously.

### WHY I DID SO

1. There was Session["keyName"] spread all over the app. It was difficult to keep track of all,i.e. what key name was used or not.
2. There was no centralized session management.
3. I could manage all session objects and its lifecycle.

Since Sessions needs to be accessible to all users across app, so, I decide it to make public static. But all of a sudden, i recalled something from SO, that , try avoid storing user specific data in public static variables. So I made session objects, accessible via internal properties and implemented a singleton pattern.Made methods static to access directly as I am not keeping any values to them. I don't know whether this is a correct approach or not ? HELP ME OUT???

### CODE

```
public sealed class SessionHelper
        {
        static readonly object _locker = new object();
        static SessionHelper _instance = null;
        private SessionHelper() { }

            /// <summary>
            /// Create a single instance of SessionHelper class
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public static SessionHelper Instance() 
            {

                    if (_instance == null)
                    {
                        lock (_locker)
                        {
                            if (_instance == null)
                            {
                                _instance = new SessionHelper();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return _instance;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Abandon Session and redirect
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="url">url in format controller/action</param>
            public static void AbandonAndRedirect(string url)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(url,true);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Abandon Session and redirect
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="url">url in format controller/action</param>
            public static void Abandon()
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
            }

            internal AuthenticationStatusCode AuthenticationStatus
            {
                get
                {
                    return (AuthenticationStatusCode) HttpContext.Current.Session["AuthStat"]  ;
                }
                set
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["AuthStat"] = value;
                }
            }
            internal string UserName
            {
                get
                {
                    return HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"] != null ? HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                }
                set
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"] = value;
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: If you are using session just for `authorization/authentication` purposes, you may want to replace it with `AspNet Identity`. Or you can implement [session based model binding](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/asp.net-mvc/1258/model-binding/12419/generic-session-based-model-binding#t=201608230648055307111) if it fits your needs.

Comment: @AdilMammadov, no its not meant only for authorization and authetication. Few other checks also using session.